# Multiple jquery noConflict files

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-widgets

I am implementing 2 sets of functions as below:-

For Window generation - Required jQuery Libraries are:
- jquery.js         (v1.3.2)
- jquery-ui.js      (v1.7.2)

I am using an extensive library used [here](http://fstoke.me/jquery/window/js/jquery/window/jquery.window.js) - which creates a jquery based dialog window using $.window{...}.

For Autocomplete/Plugin Searching, - the required Libraries that I am using are:
- jquery.js         (v1.7.2)
- jquery-ui.js      (v1.8.18)

These 2, separately, work perfectly fine. But, when used on the same page, I had to create noconflict files so that both of these functions meet somewhere in between. Thus, for now, I am using:

- jquery.js         (v1.3.2)
- jquery.js         (v1.7.2)
- jquery-ui.js      (v1.8.1)

as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jQuery_1_3_2 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

/* Here I would like to use the script below with another noConflict, because v1.8.1 (above) causes flickering of dialog boxes while dragging around & isnt smooth like the one below, which is v1.7.2:-
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://fstoke.me/jquery/window/js/jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>
*/

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://fstoke.me/jquery/window/js/jquery/window/jquery.window.js"></script>
```

When used like above, there are fair amount of visual glitches when interacting with windows. When moving windows around often other sections of the page get highlighted or flicker (quick highlight) - roughly 50% of the time. The dragging & resizing arent much smooth either.

If I remove the v1.7.2 jquery.js, the windows are a lot smoother, but the autocomplete functionality ceases to work. If I remove v1.3.2 jquery.js, the windows are not generated.

Right now, I use the functions like:-

```
function createSampleWindow() { 
sampleWnd = $.window({
.......//Code here
}(jQuery_1_3_2);
```

How can I use the v1.7.2 jquery-ui.js here too using some variable like:-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://fstoke.me/jquery/window/js/jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jq_172= $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

**Qn 1** What is the correct syntax for using both variables - jQuery_1_3_2 AND jq_172 - for the same function? Something which is [used here](http://fstoke.me/jquery/window/#example10) like:-

```
function createSampleWindow() { 
sampleWnd = $.window({
.......//Code here
}(jQuery_1_3_2, jq_172);
```

Or

```
function createSampleWindow() { 
sampleWnd = $.window({
.......//Code here
}(jQuery_1_3_2),(jq_172);
```

Doesnt work.

**Qn 2** Would it be possible to implement a large javascript such as the one [used in fstoke](http://fstoke.me/jquery/window/js/jquery/window/jquery.window.js) with jquery.js v1.7.2 instead of v1.3.2 - If someone can make a notable distinction as to why replacing v1.3.2 with v1.7.2 makes it stop working - I would be much obliged.

If I might add, since the windows are made by $.window({...}); - Replacing $.window by $.dialog doesnt make a dialog box. Is there somewhere I am going wrong? Please glance through the js file [used in fstoke](http://fstoke.me/jquery/window/js/jquery/window/jquery.window.js).

**Qn 3** Could someone point out what difference is there between [fstoke jquery-ui](http://fstoke.me/jquery/window/js/jquery/jquery-ui.js) and [cdn hosted jquery-ui](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js) - both being v1.7.2 jquery-ui.js files.

I feel it is a very long query, but I need help with this urgently. Kindly help me at the earliest.!

Comment: Using multiple versions of jQuery on a single page is a generally terrible idea.  Version 1.3.2 is **very** old - older than IE 9 in fact.  Any plugin that won't work with a newer version is probably unmaintained and thus highly suspect anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take question 1.

The correct syntax for using both versions of jQuery would be something like

```
var jQuery_1_3_2 = jQuery.noConflict(true);

function createSampleWindow() { 
    var no_op = jQuery.noop;       // refers to jQuery 1.7.2's noop function
    var no_op = $.noop;            // same as the above
    var no_op = jq_172.noop;       // same as the above
    var guid = jQuery_1_3_2.guid;  // refers to jQuery 1.3.2's guid member
}
```

In other words, you just use them, if you have them defined already. `noConflict(true)` will return `$` and `jQuery` to their previous meanings, so you can go on using them as usual.